Custom Authentication using Oauth 2.0 connected app
I have a requirement where I need to check authentication of user with third party through Oauth 2.0. The process is as follows

User clicks on Sign-in button if he is not authorise user.
If not authorize on click of sign in button user is redirected to third party application for authentication.
User puts his username & password and gets himself authenticate.
After successfull authentication through REST API callouts the access token and refresh token gets generated which I need to save for further API call.

Its working fine for single user, But how shall I implement this for multiple users belonging to same org with diffrent user names.
Please help Im stuck in with multiple user not able to find solution.

Why can't you extend your one user solution to multiple users? Your textual description is unclear on where some of these steps happen. Read up on Named/External Credentials for outbound calls from SF to 3rd party and on Auth. Providers for inbound calls from 3rd party to SF.
